# SwiftUI: How to present new views on clicking ActionSheet button?

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios13

I have an action sheet consist of three actions

1. Action_1
2. Action_2
3. Cancel

If I tap on 'Action_1', My app should present ActionView_1(). 
If I tap on 'Action_2', My app should present ActionView_2().

I got this for presenting a view

`.sheet(isPresented: $isAddSecretVisible){ActionView_1()}`.

But this for presenting a view with a Button click.

I need the same action if tap on the Actionsheet button. 
Answer needs in **SwiftUI**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can apply same logic inside the actionSheet button: https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2019/09/swiftui-actionsheet-example.html

Comment: Hey I update my code and logic [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022002/swiftui-how-to-present-new-views-on-clicking-actionsheet-button/58022287#58022287). Please take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define 2 `State`, each for each a sheet:

```
@State var isMainActionPresented = false
@State var isActionViewPresented = false
```

And a `State` to determine witch `actionSheet` to present. So you can have an enum for that like:

```
enum ActionViewMode {
    case first
    case second
}
```

And a helper extension on that:

```
extension ActionViewMode {
    var view: some View {
        switch self {
            case .first: return ActionView1()
            case .second: return ActionView2()
        }
    }
}
```

Then on click of any `Button` or `ActionSheet.Button`, toggle the desired state. Look at the complete `ContentView` code below:

```
@State var actionViewMode = ActionViewMode.first

@State var isMainActionPresented = false
@State var isActionViewPresented = false

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        self.isMainActionPresented = true
    }) {
        Text("ActionSheet")
    }
    .actionSheet(isPresented: $isMainActionPresented) {
        ActionSheet(
            title: Text("Title"),
            message: Text("Message"),
            buttons: [
                .default(
                    Text("Action_1"),
                    action: {
                        self.actionViewMode = .first
                        self.isActionViewPresented = true
                }),
                .default(
                    Text("Action_2"),
                    action: {
                        self.actionViewMode = .second
                        self.isActionViewPresented = true
                }),
                .cancel()
        ])
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isActionViewPresented) {
        self.actionViewMode.view
    }
}
```

SwiftUI will handle the rest.

**Note that** you can't chain multiple sheets one after another, because each one overrides previous somehow.

Comment: If you get the error `Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types` cast the views you are returning in the `ActionViewMode` extension to `AnyView`!

Answer (score 0):

Reference link : [SwiftUI](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2019/09/swiftui-actionsheet-example.html)

```
ActionSheet(title: Text("iOSDevCenters"), message: Text("SubTitle"), buttons: [
            .default(Text("Action_1"), action: {
                                print("Action_1")
                                ActionView_1()
                            }),
            .destructive(Text("Cancel"))
         ])
})
```

Comment: This won't present ActionView_1, just initialise it.